# Series about a hunted female vampire with reference to Indian mythology

Tags: story-identification

This series is about a female vampire who is being hunted. There is only one other Vampire in the series, but he doesn't come up in the first book. There are references to Indian mythological characters like Krishna as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The series you mean is probably [The Last Vampire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Vampire), by Christopher Pike. (There seem to be many books with the same name). Also, [Flipkart link](http://www.flipkart.com/author/christopher-pike).

Comment: That's it thanks. Once you answered, I saw that there are movies based on this series too, now they're on my to-watch list :)